# Difference between default export and named export

Tags: javascript, import, export, default

As I understand, exported functions can be imported with whatever name you please. For example, you can have a file `functions.js` that contains the code `export default sayFruit` and a main file `main.js` that contains the code `import whatever from './functions.js`. Then, `whatever()` outputs the same as `sayFruit()` in the `functions.js` file.
Now, is the fact that you can name the imported function whatever you would like the *only* difference between named export and default export?

---

Note: I suppose "named" export is the equivalente of writing `export {functionName}`.

Comment: Named exports can be renamed aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single default export. As such, when importing you can call it whatever you want. If you have multiple exports, you have to call them something when you export so you can specify in the file you're importing into which function/constant/etc you want from the source file. You can also rename named exports when you import them/

You can have a mix of default and named as well.

```
// asd.js
const Foo = "bar"
export default Foo
export const Baz = "bax"

// other file
import MyFoo, { Baz } from "./asd"

// other file with renamed Baz import
import MyFoo, { Baz: MyBaz } from "./asd"
```

but yea otherwise it's the same thing.

What I use as a reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export